# @font-face declaration for Amstelvar (italic variable font)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

What's the proper way to define `@font-face` declarations for [Amstelvar](https://github.com/TypeNetwork/Amstelvar) italic (variable) font?

Here are the font faces declarations I used:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Amstelvar';
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('amstelvar-roman.woff2') format('woff2-variations'),
      url('amstelvar-roman.woff2') format('woff2');
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Amstelvar';
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: oblique 0deg 10deg;
    src: url('amstelvar-italic.woff2') format('woff2-variations'),
      url('amstelvar-italic.woff2') format('woff2');
  }
```

Add this is the class I apply to the italic text:

```
.italic {
  font-style: italic,

  @supports (font-variation-settings: normal): {
    font-variation-settings: 'slnt' -10,
    font-style: oblique 10deg,
  }
}
```

Here is the [live example](https://deploy-preview-41--skok.netlify.app/blog/typography/).
The word *italic* has to be italicized in "Test Page with italics and bold" header, but unfortunately, it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted this on twitter but figured I'd add it here too:

Found a few things: the subsets of Amstelvar lost their variation axes so aren't behaving properly. Also: it has an italic axis & not slant, & since roman/italic are separate files, you can just use family grouping & font-style: italic Have a look: https://codepen.io/jpamental/pen/wvKdmPp

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amstelvar';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/Amstelvar-Roman.woff2),
  url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/Amstelvar-Roman.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amstelvar';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/Amstelvar-Italic.woff2),
  url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/57225/Amstelvar-Italic.woff2) format('woff2');
}
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
```